# UnsatisfiedLinkError - GSvideo library on Processing

Tags: processing

We're currently working on an art project where we're recording video with GSvideo library and showing another video simultaneously with VLC. Our project works fine on three Windows 7 computers we have tried, but the ones we have available for the exhibition gives the following error:

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   can't load library gio-2.0 (gio-2.0|libgio-2.0|libgio-2.0-0) with
>   -Djna.library.path=//Desktop/media_art_installation/sktetch/libraries/GSVideo/library\gstreamer\windows64.
>   Last error:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library
>   'gio-2.0': The specified module could not be found.

We noticed that the path includes both "/" and "\". We know that our school computers use Java 1.6. Neither we or our teachers or tech support can find the answer to our question. So, why doesn't it work on school computers?

The line that gives the error in our code is as follows:

```
 movieMaker = new GSMovieMaker(this, 640, 480, "data/" + getCurrentFileName(), GSMovieMaker.THEORA, GSMovieMaker.MEDIUM, fps);
```

Comment: The path you list spells "sketch" incorrectly... Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For now let's assume the spelling of the library path is not the problem...

If you parse the error you mention, you see that it cannot find the module. It lists a library path, which must be incorrect on the machines used for exhibition. Were the Win 7 machines 32- or 64-bit? What type of machines are used for exhibition? (Win XP? Macs? 32-bit 64-bit). Any difference between the test and exhibition machines would be a red flag.

Also, how are you pointing to this library? After Googling a bit I've come up with the following:

- A [thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/gsvideo/discussion/813596/thread/87f463dd) on sourceforce recommends using the `GSVideo.localGStreamerPath` to point to the gstreamer library.
- Another [thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t390018-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-cant-load-library-from-jni-code.html) noted that using `System.loadLibrary` solved the problem (second to last post in thread).

---

So the second suggestion might look like this for you:

```
System.loadLibrary("/Desktop/media_art_installation/sketch/libraries/GSVideo/library/gstreamer/windows64");
```